# magento 2.3.3 not sending any mail

Tags: magento2, php, email, magento2.3.3, contact-form

I just installed Magento 2.3.3 in the Cpanel using Installatron. I didn't add any product. I changed the email in store->configuration->Email Options->Send Emails To.
but no email is coming when I submit the contact form. because of this issue, I reinstalled Magento before.
I search for a solution but nothing worked, can anyone help me I am new to Magento
you can check from this URL:  **http://zahratalebtsama.ae/**

- my emails addresses are working fine
- server sending emails fine check from this URL : http://zahratalebtsama.ae/mail_test.php

Comment: check your mx records and try to send email where you have setup your mx records. if you don't know then generate a ticket to server support

Answer (score 0):

Emails are a bit broken in 2.3.3

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/25338

Either follow patch guide or upgrade to 2.3.4

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/release-notes/release-notes-2-3-3-open-source.html#apply-the-emailmessageinterface-backward-compatibility-issue-patch-to-resolve-an-email-interface-backward-incompatibility-issue

Comment: i got the sales mail after one day. in the cron schedule table, every sales emails are pending. do i have to add cron job in Cpanel or it will add automatically?